# Issue Updating Google Apps - "Not Signed Correctly"

Tags: google-play-store, 4.2-jelly-bean, gmail, google-play-music, aokp

First and forehand, I am running JB 4.2.2 AOKP on my AT&T Samsung Galaxy S3. I have the latest gapps package installed after every time I flash an update to my ROM.

For some reason though, whenever I try to update either Gmail or Play Music, I get the error "Package file was not signed correctly. Uninstall the previous copy of the app and try again."

I can't uninstall the apps because they are used as system apps, and the best I can do is disable them, but that still didn't let me update them. I'm sure it has something to do with the gapps package that I flashed, but why does it not give me the same error when I update Play Movies and Play Magazines?

I do not use Titanium Backup to back up any of my apps, so I saw that that was a problem for some other people. If however, there is another question that relates more to mine, I will be glad to go and check it out, but after my looking I did not find a solution to my specific problem. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Here's the link to the [gapps package](http://www.task650.jocoje.com/Gapps/gapps-4.2.2-jb-6.12.2013-signed.zip) that I installed as well as the [exact ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1766684) I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android, every package is cryptographically signed by its author. To be an upgrade, the new package has to be signed with the same key as the old package. Since packages can read previous versions' data files, this is an important security precaution.

The error you get tells you that the update you're trying to install was not signed using the same key as the package you had flashed to the ROM. Either the original package you flashed, or the new package, was signed by a different developer.

You should either obtain an update from the same source you originally got the gapps package from, or flash a new ROM with a gapps package from the same source you're trying to update from. We may be able to help further with this if you edit your question to say where you got these packages from.

Comment: I linked to the gapps and ROM I am using. Since the developer updates the gapps more regularly than most, he must be tweaking them slightly for his ROM. I guess I just have to wait until he incorporates the updates.